Purpose of mov %rax,-0x10(%rbp) then -0x10(%rbp),%rax
I disassembled a function that made a syscall to compare why mine wasn't working, and I noticed these two strange instructions after the syscall instruction when this same function is compiled with GCC. Can anyone explain to me what purpose this serves?
mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax

If I am reading it correctly, it places the value of %rax (the syscall return value) into -0x10(%rbp) (two words behind the current stack frame), which I think is the word prior to the return address on the stack. Then it reverses this. Both the memory address and the register will have the same value after the first instruction, so the second appears to be a no-op.
My guess is that this is a ramshackle "memory barrier" to ensure that all memory operations are done before returning (like mfence, I think). But I cannot find documentation of this practice, and the GCC source code is just innavigable for me to figure out where this is coming from.
The code being used to generate this uses both the memory and cc clobbers within inline assembly, if that is important.
Also, here is the entire function, just for context:
0000000000401cda <sys_mmap>:
  401cda:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  401cde:   55                      push   %rbp
  401cdf:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  401ce2:   48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
  401ce6:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  401cea:   89 55 dc                mov    %edx,-0x24(%rbp)
  401ced:   89 4d d8                mov    %ecx,-0x28(%rbp)
  401cf0:   44 89 45 d4             mov    %r8d,-0x2c(%rbp)
  401cf4:   4c 89 4d c8             mov    %r9,-0x38(%rbp)
  401cf8:   c7 45 fc 09 00 00 00    movl   $0x9,-0x4(%rbp)
  401cff:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  401d02:   48 98                   cltq   
  401d04:   48 8b 55 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rdx
  401d08:   48 89 d7                mov    %rdx,%rdi
  401d0b:   48 8b 55 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
  401d0f:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  401d12:   8b 55 dc                mov    -0x24(%rbp),%edx
  401d15:   48 63 d2                movslq %edx,%rdx
  401d18:   8b 4d d8                mov    -0x28(%rbp),%ecx
  401d1b:   48 63 c9                movslq %ecx,%rcx
  401d1e:   49 89 ca                mov    %rcx,%r10
  401d21:   8b 4d d4                mov    -0x2c(%rbp),%ecx
  401d24:   48 63 c9                movslq %ecx,%rcx
  401d27:   49 89 c8                mov    %rcx,%r8
  401d2a:   4c 8b 4d c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%r9
  401d2e:   0f 05                   syscall 
  401d30:   48 89 45 f0             mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
  401d34:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  401d38:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  401d39:   c3                      retq  

Clarification: This is x86-64 assembly / Linux ABI.

This is likely the consequence of the code having been compiled without optimisations.  The compiler stores the return value of the syscall into memory as it has been told not to optimise that away.

"Then it reverses this. ... so the second appears to be a no-op" — and so is the first, if the objective is to return the syscall's return value here.  It is correct but not optimal, but so what?  There's a lot of suboptimal code out there.

Near duplicate: Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?
